# Node.js server as both a Socket.io host and client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

For historical reasons and technical necessity our app has the following configuration:

[image]

The node.js workers need to connect (using Socket.IO-Client) to the node.js database access point AND listen for a connection from the node.js servers (using Socket.IO).  I am having issues getting both to connect and I am wondering, do I need to use different ports for each Socket.IO-client or can they operate on the same port?

Right now, things seem to connect for a moment, but no data is passed along.

Adding larger version of the image:  [Larger Image](http://postimg.org/image/eo61o8pln/full/)

Comment: Multiple clients can connect to the same server on the same port.  That is the usual configuration.  Multiple servers on the same box cannot listen for incoming connections on the same port as it would not be clear who was supposed to get the incoming connection and thus the OS will not allow it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, but can a server listen on port 443 (ie. act as a server) for Websockets AND connect over port 443 (ie. as a client) to a different server via a Websocket?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  No issue.  The outbound port number is actually assigned automatically by the system and is not the same as the port you are connecting to and is not something you have to worry about.